# Breeze 1.4.0 Inline Count when sorted by a nested property path

Tags: javascript, breeze

I know the release notes say 1.4.0 is supposed to fix the issue with inlineCount not functioning properly when sorted by a nested property path.  I've downloaded the newest version (1.4.0) and while I do now get a value in inlineCount, it doesn't seem to be correct when using the nested path to sort.  I have 6 records and do a take(5) with inlineCount and the inlineCount value is 5 instead of 6.  If I removed the sort I do get the correct 6.  This is my query, is there something I'm still doing incorrectly or is this just a new issue?

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Surveys')
            .where("facilityId", "eq", whereClause)
            .skip(currentPage * 5).take(5)
            .expand("Facility, SurvCat, SurveyCitation, SurvCat.SurveyCategories, SurveyStatus")
            .inlineCount(true);
```

Edit - The original question said 6 instead of 5 with the nested path sort, it was reversed.

Comment: As the docs state, inlineCount is supposed to return a property containing the value of count *if where and filter clauses only are applied*, so your take clause is ignored.  In your question you state that you get 6 either way - was that a typo??

Comment: The numbers were switched.  The issue I'm seeing is the inlineCount should return 6, but with the nested sort it returns 5.  There are 6 records and if I use a non nested sort I get the correct inlineCount of 6.  The only reason I mention the take is because if I change the take to 10 or 6, the inlineCount returns 6, so it appears as though it's only return the actual returned data.results array length instead of the total record count.

Comment: Ok now the question makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this bug was fixed in the breeze 1.5.x series of releases.